# Blockdiagonal variation grid

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have the feeling I am missing something intuitive in my solution for generating a partially varied block-diagonal grid. In any case, I would like to get rid of the loop in my function (for the sake of challenge...)

Given tuples of parameters, number of intervals and percentage variation:

```
params = [100 0.5   1
           24   1 0.9];
nint   = 1; 
perc   = 0.1;
```

The desired output should be:

```
pspacegrid(params,perc,nint)
ans =
   90.0000    0.5000    1.0000
  100.0000    0.5000    1.0000
  110.0000    0.5000    1.0000
  100.0000    0.4500    1.0000
  100.0000    0.5000    1.0000
  100.0000    0.5500    1.0000
  100.0000    0.5000    0.9000
  100.0000    0.5000    1.0000
  100.0000    0.5000    1.1000
   21.6000    1.0000    0.9000
   24.0000    1.0000    0.9000
   26.4000    1.0000    0.9000
   24.0000    0.9000    0.9000
   24.0000    1.0000    0.9000
   24.0000    1.1000    0.9000
   24.0000    1.0000    0.8100
   24.0000    1.0000    0.9000
   24.0000    1.0000    0.9900
```

where you can see that the variation occurs at the values expressed by this mask:

```
mask =
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     1     0     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
     0     0     1
```

The function `pspacegrid()` is:

```
function out = pspacegrid(params, perc, nint)
% PSPACEGRID Generates a parameter space grid for sensitivity analysis

% Size and number of variation steps
sz     = size(params);
nsteps = nint*2+1;

% Preallocate output
out    = reshape(permute(repmat(params,[1,1,nsteps*sz(2)]),[3,1,2]),[],sz(2));

% Mask to index positions where to place interpolated 
[tmp{1:sz(2)}] = deal(true(nsteps,1));
mask           = repmat(logical(blkdiag(tmp{:})),sz(1),1);

zi = cell(sz(1),1);
% LOOP per each parameter tuple
for r = 1:sz(1)
    % Columns, rows, rows to interpolate and lower/upper parameter values
    x     = 1:sz(2);
    y     = [1; nint*2+1];
    yi    = (1:nint*2+1)';
    z     = [params(r,:)*(1-perc); params(r,:)*(1+perc)];
    % Interpolated parameters 
    zi{r} = interp2(x,y,z, x, yi);
end
out(mask) = cat(1,zi{:});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it, building off your pre-loop code:

```
params = [100 0.5   1
           24   1 0.9];
nint   = 1; 
perc   = 0.1;

sz     = size(params);
nsteps = nint*2+1;

% Preallocate output
out    = reshape(permute(repmat(params,[1,1,nsteps*sz(2)]),[3,1,2]),[],sz(2));

%Map of the percentage moves
[tmp{1:sz(2)}] = deal(linspace(-perc,perc,nint*2+1)');
mask = repmat(blkdiag(tmp{:}),sz(1),1) + 1; %Add one so we can just multiply at the end

mask.*out
```

So instead of making your mask replicate the ones I made it replicate the percentage moves each element makes which is a repeating pattern, the basic element is made like this:

```
linspace(-perc,perc,nint*2+1)'
```

Then it's as simple as adding `1` to the whole thing and multiplying by your `out` matrix

I tested it as follows:

```
me = mask.*out;
you = pspacegrid(params, perc, nint);

check = me - you < 0.0001;

mean(check(:))
```

Seemed to work when I fiddled with the inputs. However I did get an error with your function, I had to change `true(...)` to `ones(...)`. This might be because I'm running it online which probably uses Octave rather than Matlab.

Comment: If you try my function with `nint = 2` you will see that the behaviour I am looking for is: set the range of variation to be `[x*(1-perc), x(1+perc)]`, divide this range into `nint` periods. Instead, your approach extends the range. Intuitively, I know by how much I want to get far away from the original parameter and how fine the grid should be.

Comment: @OlegKomarov So the `(-perc*nint:perc:perc*nint)'` should be changed to `linspace(-perc,perc,nint*2+1)'`

Comment: My gut feeling was right (that I was missing something), thanks for the percentage variation solution. Also, your code is faster (although trades against ram).